# NextJs 13 broken static export

Tags: next.js, deployment, next.js13

I've been trying to export my website to static, but for some reason im unable to do so, so for a default generated next 13 app i use this config

```js
//my next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: "export",
};

export default nextConfig;
```

so when i run `npm run build` i get /out folder in which there is index.html page,
when i open it, I get broken html and these errors:

[image: Inspector tool screenshot]

I've tried manually fixing eact src link and other link and it seems to work, but I believe that i'm missing some configs

do I need to use some other type of serving the pages, do I need to add some configs?
Thanks!